# The sequence 1, 3, 4, 9, 10, 12, 13... consists of integers that are either powers of 3 or sums of distinct powers of 3. What is the 100th term?

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic

I really have no idea how to start. There is no pattern, except that the mod 3 of all the terms alternates between 1 and 0. Is this a key step?

Comment: Write them in base $3.$ Thus you have the sequence $1,10,11,100,...$

Comment: In the base-$3$-number system these are the numbers having no digit $2$. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Why is 9 not in the sequence?

Comment: @DavidQuinn My mistake.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A005836](https://oeis.org/A005836).

Comment: Explain the close vote...How is this not math?

Comment: @GerardL. You can refer to https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1986_AIME_Problems/Problem_7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert $100$ into a binary string and calculate $a_0+3a_1+9a_2+\cdots 3^ka_k$, where $a_0,a_1,\cdots a_k$ are the digits of the binary string. The result is $$3^6+3^5+3^2=981$$ (Note $2^6+2^5+2^2=100$)

In this manner you can calculate the $n$-th number of the sequence for any $n$.

Comment: How did you ge from the first step to the second? I am not familiar with this way of solving it.

Comment: Since the numbers are exactly those not having digit $2$ in the representation to base $3$, they can be interpreted as binary strings. And if a number is smaller than another interpreted in base $2$, the same is true if the numbers are interpreted in base $3$. So, you just have to interprete the $100$-th binary numer ($100$ in binary representation) in base $3$.

Comment: To formulate it even easier : Take the base $2$-representation and replace the base by $3$, that is all what you have to do.

Comment: So first I would make the series base 2, and then keep everything the same except mark is as base 3?

Comment: This kind of operation occurs in the Godstein-sequence (but in a more complicated way, we have iterated representations there) and it is called "bumping up the base"

Comment: @GerardL. Yes, that's it.

Comment: And how would I convert 100 into the binary string?

Comment: The easiest way is to divide by $2$ (with remainder) and noting the remainders until you reach $1$. Then, append $1$. The digits in reverse give the desired string. Example $11$ : We get the numbers $5,2,1$ with remainders $1,1,0$. Appending $1$ gives $1,1,0,1$. So, $1011$ is the desired string.

Comment: Is there a reason to add 1?

Comment: Formally, you can apply the last step as dividing $1$ by $2$ with remainder $1$. So, if you stop with $0$, you need not append $1$. You will always reach $1$ (which must be the case because every positive integer has a binary representation starting with a $1$)

Comment: So the binary representation of 100 is 10011.

Comment: No, it is $1100100$. You must also note the two zeros at the start.